# PutFile not sending file from active directory?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, ftp, window

```
pConnect->SetCurrentDirectory( "C:\\FilesToSendToServer" ); //Need this set on client, i believe currently setting on server.
CFtpFileFind finder(pConnect);
finder.FindFile( "*", INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT );
finder.FindNextFile();
CString filename = finder.GetFileName(); //finds the only file in that directory - test.txt

pConnect->PutFile( filename, "C:\\FilesReceived\\FILE_SENT_FROM_CLIENT.txt", FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 1 )) //filename set to test.txt correctly
```

On the client I have the directory `FilesToSendToServer` with one test file - "test.txt"

I also have the working directory of this application on the client - `C\uploadApp\`

The code above sets the current directory correctly and "finds" the test file.

However, when `PutFile` executes with the filename parameter set correctly (test.txt) the functin returns the error file not found.

So as a test, I put a copy of test.txt in the applications working directory `uploadApp` and it DID send the file to the server.

Why does the file need to be in the working directory to be sent if the active directory is set in the CFtpConnection object?

(Does this mean for any file I want to send from the client I have to copy it over to the directory of the application?)

Thank You.

**EDIT**
Looks like `SetCurrentDirectory` calls `FtpSetCurrentDirectory` which

> determine the remote site's current working directory

So for a GET this would make sense...is there an alternate function for a PUT - to set the active directory of the local machine? (FYI - Unable to make a distinction between the remote directory on the server testing on same machine...if testing on target the SetCurrentDirectory should fail, as it is looking on the server...I assume)

Comment: FTP clients work somewhat goofy in regards to working directories at times.  You might want to try to chdir to the folder you want to send from instead of giving full paths.  I wouldn't think you should want to copy files around.

Comment: Which function would I use to chdir? Don't see one as part of this class....also, I thought ultimately that is what SetCurentDirectory did?

Comment: @Tommy : `chdir` _is_ the function. (Well, [`_chdir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx) actually...)

Comment: @ildjarn: Will this still be compatible with the cFtpConnection->PutFile()...how will this object know the directory has been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were meaning to call the win32 API [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will change the **local** directory instead of the **remote** directory that pConnect->SetCurrentDirectory changes. Try ::SetCurrentDirectory if you're in a namespace. Of course your working directory will no longer be C:\uploadApp...

Comment: Great this what I needed, to set the local directory. is there an equivalent to the CFtpFileFind finder() to search the local directory? also, PutFile will need to be of this objects SetCurrentDirectory?

Comment: @Tommy : FWIW, `SetCurrentDirectory` does the exact same thing as `_chdir`, which @TomKerr initially recommended.

Comment: So either way sets the local directory, how does pConnect->PutFile? object know the local directory has been changed?

Comment: You could use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) to search local directories. PutFile will use the current directory only if you give it a relative path for the local file, ie. just a filename. If you give it an absolute path (from C: or D: etc), then you don't have to change the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

To change the working directory on the client side you should be able to call Win32 [::SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You will find it easier to get this code working if you get in the habit of checking for errors on any Win32 call, including those encapsulated within MFC.

Comment: thank you, I will be sure to check for errors. however, in this case there was no error in the code, it found the directory correctly, just couldn't distinguish as it is all on the same machine...

Comment: What did you get back from the original call `pConnect->SetCurrentDirectory( "C:\\FilesToSendToServer" );` - I would think that would fail if the dir did not exist on the server.

Comment: if you see my lsat edit, because I am testing all on the same machine, the directory is available to the application.

Comment: All those functions in `CFtpFileFind` apply to the SERVER.  For local file operations, you need to use the raw WIN32 functions with the same name, as you did with SetCurrentDirectory, eg. FindFirstFile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx) etc.